# CakePHP multiple counts in one query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to get multiple totals under different conditions from one table called Posts in CakePHP 3

Is this possible

count post_sent where post_sent = 0

count post_sent where post_sent = 1

count rsvp where rsvp = 3

```
SELECT count(Case when post_sent=0 then 1 else 0 end) as post_not_sent, 
       count(Case when post_sent=1 then 1 else 0 end) as post_sent,
       count(Case when rsvp=3 then 1 else 0 end) as rsvp_sent
FROM content_form
```

Comment: Have you tried searching the docs for case statements https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements

Comment: Great thanks, I did not see this section. Exactly what I need